# If then Python logic returns incorrect queryset Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

If no filter has been applied the page should display all users, possibly

`{% for user in users %}`

If `request.POST` `ProfileFilter` has been submitted and there are matches, the page should return the users in the queryset or

`{% for profile in filter.qs %}`

If the `ProfileFilter` does not return any results on `request.POST`, `No results found` should be displayed.

With the current logic below the page is returning `No results, try again?` before anything is posted which I assume is because `filter` is always defined (so `{% if profile in filter.qs %}` is always `True`) so the `{% for user in users %}` is never running.

So is it possible to define some kind of logic with `{% for profile in filter.qs %}` to return

1) all users if the queryset hasn't yet been posted

2) matching users if it has been posted

3) `no results found` if no users match?

Someone please point me in the right direction! Thank you.

html

```
{% if filter %}
    {% for profile in filter.qs %}
        <h5>{{ profile.user.first_name }}</h5>
        <p>{{ profile.age }}</p>
    {% empty %}
        <h1>No results, try again?</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for user in users %}
        <h5>{{ user.first_name }}</h5>
        <p>{{ user.profile.age }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
class xxx(View):
    template_name = 'xxx'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filter = ProfileFilter(request.GET, Profile.objects.none())
        context = {
            'users': User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id),
            'filter': filter,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        queryset = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
        if 'radius' in request.POST:
            print(request.POST)
            radius_km = request.POST.get('radius', 0)
            queryset = queryset.annotate(
                radius_sqr=pow(models.F('user__loc__latitude') -
                request.user.loc.latitude, 2) + pow(models.F('user__loc__longitude') -
                request.user.loc.longitude, 2)
                ).filter(
                radius_sqr__lte=pow(int(radius_km) / 9, 2)
                )
        filter = ProfileFilter(request.POST, queryset)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'filter': filter, 'users': users})
```

Comment: First of all, careful with calling a template variable `user`, as that hides the default variable that holds the currently logged-in user.

Comment: I assume `filter.qs` is a normal quesryset. Have you tried `{% if filter.qs.exists %}` instead of `{% if filter %}` ?

Comment: Hi Ralf, thanks for your comments, that's good to know about calling the variable template `user`. What would be a better name for it? `filter.qs` is in Filters.py as `class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):` I've just tried `{% if filter.qs.exists %}` however it still returns a list of all users even when there are no matches for the `filter` applied.

Comment: I've fixed it, I had to change `filter` to `filter = ProfileFilter(request.GET, Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id))` and take out all if them statements and just run `{% for profile in filter.qs %}` with an empty tag that shows `no results`